# checkbox and clickable icon columns stop working in Vuetify 2

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm porting an application from Vuetify 1.5 to version 2. So far I have only one problem which I can't find an answer in documentation or forums
The trouble is in two last columns in the table:
- one is checkbox for `props.item.admin` rendered as string "false" or "true"
- and 2nd is a clickable icon not rendered at all (in browser I see completely empty table cell)

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="accounts"
  :search="search"
  :loading="loadingProgress"
  class="elevation-1"
  @click:row="openAccount">
  <v-progress-linear v-slot:progress color="blue" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <tr >
      <td class="text-xs-left"> {{ props.item.customerName }} </td>
      <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.techCode }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.email }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.phone }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.ext }}</td>

      <td class="text-xs-center">
        <v-checkbox
          v-model="props.item.admin"
          readonly
        ></v-checkbox>
      </td>
      <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
        <v-icon
          @click.stop="confirmDeleteAccount($event, props.item)">
          delete
        </v-icon>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

PS. Forgot to add that outside table icons are rendered without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like instead rendering table row inside data-table, vuetify team suggest to use `template slots`. Unfortunately, the documentation explains neither a new approach nor cells binding to values.

The following v-data-table set-up works for me

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="accounts"
  :search="search"
  :loading="loadingProgress"
  class="elevation-1"
  @click:row="openAccount">
  <v-progress-linear v-slot:progress color="blue" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
  <template v-slot:item.admin="{ item }">
    <v-icon>
      {{ item.admin ? "mdi-checkbox-marked" : "mdi-checkbox-blank-outline" }}
    </v-icon>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
    <v-icon @click.stop="confirmDeleteAccount(item)">delete</v-icon>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```